# Problems using certificates after installing with PowerShell

Tags: windows, powershell, certificate, pfx

I have several thousand machines which need 3 .pfx certificates installed on the LocalMachine. I use the following command to see how many certificates are installed on a machine:

```
Get-ChildItem Cert:\LocalMachine -Recurse | measure
```

On a fresh machine, there are 119 certificates installed

[image: 119 Certificates]

When I install the certificates manually (Double click, local machine, enter password, automatically select the certificate store based on the certificate type) I see that 138 certificates are installed.

[image: 138 Certificates]

When I install the certificates with PowerShell using the following code:

```
$pass = ConvertTo-SecureString -String "Password" -AsPlainText -Force
Import-PfxCertificate -FilePath D:\files\certname.pfx -Password $pass -CertStoreLocation Cert:\LocalMachine\Root -Exportable
```

I see that there are 143 certificates installed.

[image: 143 Certificates]

When I attempt to use Connect-ExchangeOnline with machines that have the certificates manually installed, I am successful. When I attempt to use Connect-ExchangeOnline with machines that have the certificates installed with PowerShell, I get an error. It seems the certificates are not usable when installed with PowerShell.

Can anyone shed some light on this situation for me?

Comment: Rather than auto select the store when doing it manually, on a fresh device, have you tried specifically choosing the Trusted Root store, does that still work?

Comment: Hi KG-DROID. Thank you for the thought, it turns out that the script I am running is not importing the certificates to the ROOT store, they are instead importing them to the CA store, even though ROOT is clearly defined in -CertStoreLocation , I'm not sure what would cause this, as I have admin and the ISE is running elevated.

Comment: Not sure why the powershell command isnt working for you, but you could try importing it via the classes instead: `$Cert = [System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2]::new("path to pfx file", "password")
$CertStore = [System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Store]::new('Root', 'LocalMachine')
$CertStore.Open([System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.OpenFlags]::ReadWrite)
$CertStore.Add($Cert)
$CertStore.Close()`
You just need to add in your file path and the secure password